# Laravel, get_declared_classes() не видит ни одну модель кроме User

Tags: php, laravel, рефлексия

Все модели создавались артисаном. При вызове `get_declared_classes()` Не получаю 
все модели, только модель User. При этом если вызвать `class_exists('App\SomeModel')`, возвращает `true`. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_declared_classes` возвращает список объявленный в скрипте классов на момент своего вызова. Не все классы в проекте, а только те, что уже были объявлены.

[`class_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) ищет указанный класс в списке объявленных классов, если не находит в этом списке, то:

- если второй аргумент указан как `false` - то функция вернёт `false`
- если второй аргумент не указан или указан `true` - то функция вызовет механизм [автозагрузки](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) классов. Если этот механизм найдёт заданный класс - то функция вернёт `true`.

Сравните списки

```
var_dump(get_declared_classes());
var_dump(class_exists('App\SomeModel', false)); // ожидается false
var_dump(get_declared_classes()); // список не изменился
var_dump(class_exists('App\SomeModel')); // вернул true
var_dump(get_declared_classes()); // в списке появился новый класс
```

Comment: а есть ли возможность получить список не объявленных классов или может есть какой-то другой способ? Просто мне нужно получить список всех классов и проверить какие из них реализуют интерфейс.

Comment: Поскольку вы можете добавить свой и в любом количестве autoload с любой логикой - PHP не может никак загрузить все классы - он просто не знает, где вы могли реализовать их поиск (не говоря о том, что класс мог объявляться даже в eval). Но это знаете вы - значит можете написать код, который сходит по всем директориям с классами и сделает include.